# Pygame; checking if the shortest distance between any points on two rectangles is less than x amount?

Tags: python, pygame, distance, rectangles

Basically I'm making a game with pygame and there will be rectangles moving around the screen. Player 1's and player 2's. If any of player 1's units are within x distance of player 2's units, then fire. If I do distance from center, then it won't be accurate since some of these rectangle will be much longer on one side and will be well within the range of being fired upon but the center won't be. I've been searching but haven't been able to find a solution to this problem.

EDIT: Removed circles. I will have circles too but I'll be treating them like rectangles and using their .rect. They're small and the 2 pixel inaccuracy doesn't matter.

Comment: What do you mean that some rectangles will be longer on one side of it's center? The center is always defined as being the point with equal distance between two opposite edges. If you mean that you want to fire when the players overlap then just check for when the rectangles collide, a.k.a. [`if rect1.colliderect(rect2)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect). Or you could temporarily scale ([inflate](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate)) the rects x pixels bigger and then check for collision.

Comment: I didn't think about inflating it, that seems like it would work. I had meant that if there's two long skinny rectangles, they'll bump into each other before they even show up as within x distance of each other, since the distance is from their centers. Inflating seems like a good solution for it though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can think of right now:
It compares the corners of the rectangle with the center of the circle. If that is not enough for you you can just add center points along the rectangles edges.

Not a perfect solution, but depending on the game you are writing it should be enough

```
def isInRange(rectangle, circle):
    return (
        (rectangle.topleft.x     - circle.centerx)**2 + (rectangle.topleft.y     - circle.centery)**2 <= (mindist + r_circle)**2 or #circle in upper  left  quadrant of rectangle
        (rectangle.bottomleft.x  - circle.centerx)**2 + (rectangle.bottomleft.y  - circle.centery)**2 <= (mindist + r_circle)**2 or #circle in bottom left  quadrant of rectangle
        (rectangle.bottomright.x - circle.centerx)**2 + (rectangle.bottomright.y - circle.centery)**2 <= (mindist + r_circle)**2 or #circle in bottom right quadrant of rectangle
        (rectangle.topright.x    - circle.centerx)**2 + (rectangle.topright.y    - circle.centery)**2 <= (mindist + r_circle)**2    #circle in top    right quadrant of rectangle
        )
```

Comment: It takes a rectangle and a circle as arguments, this wouldn't work for checking the distance between two rectangles. I should've explained clearer in the original post. I would just treat the circles like rectangles and use it's .rect to check distace. The circles are small enough that it doesn't matter.

Comment: no in both cases it uses .rect objects. if the circle is very small it does not matter

Comment: Oh. But it's comparing the center of the second object to the corner points in the first. How would I compare all the corners of both objects to each other? Like, all points with all points.